# Why this regression model with one predictor don't work?

Tags: r, multiple-regression, t-test, model-selection, model

I have this R script. I want to estimate the coefficient of the dependent variable Y based on several regression.

```
set.seed(0)
n = 1000
X_1 <- rnorm(n)
X_2 <- rnorm(n)
Y <- X_1 + 100*X_2 + rnorm(n)


#linear regression:
reg1 = lm(Y ~ X_1)
reg2 = lm(Y ~ X_2)
reg3 = lm(Y ~ X_1 + X_2)
```

Results:

```
> summary(reg1)

Call:
lm(formula = Y ~ X_1)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-301.80  -70.24   -0.08   75.04  304.51 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  -2.4993     3.2708  -0.764    0.445
X_1          -0.3074     3.2786  -0.094    0.925

Residual standard error: 103.4 on 998 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  8.81e-06,  Adjusted R-squared:  -0.0009932 
F-statistic: 0.008792 on 1 and 998 DF,  p-value: 0.9253

> summary(reg2)

Call:
lm(formula = Y ~ X_2)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.2089 -0.6960 -0.0478  0.6994  3.2923 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -0.01613    0.03158   -0.511     0.61    
X_2         99.98781    0.03056 3272.139   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  
0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.9984 on 998 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9999,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9999 
F-statistic: 1.071e+07 on 1 and 998 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

> summary(reg3)

Call:
lm(formula = Y ~ X_1 + X_2)

Residuals:
       Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max 
-7.496e-13 -1.490e-14 -5.700e-15  3.300e-15  6.326e-12 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error    t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -7.720e-15  6.414e-15 -1.204e+00    0.229    
X_1          1.000e+00  6.428e-15  1.556e+14   <2e-16 ***
X_2          1.000e+02  6.206e-15  1.611e+16   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  
0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.027e-13 on 997 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:      1, Adjusted R-squared:      1 
F-statistic: 1.298e+32 on 2 and 997 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

I want to understand :

- Why the first model(reg1) couldn't capture the relationship between Y and X_1 whereas the second model could do so (reg2) ?
- Why adding X_2 to the first model could solve the problem (see reg3) ?

Thanks you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Everything works as intended.**

The crucial thing to notice is that the effect of `X_1` is minuscule compared to `X_2`. This is evident in the huge standard error (and thus variability) of the coefficient in the first regression. When you take `X_2` into account in your third regression, you're basically removing its influence and the effect of `X_1` can be easily "detected". Because `X_1` and `X_2` are uncorrelated, there is no omitted variable bias. But let's take it from the beginning.

The standard error for `X_1` in the first regression is given by
$$\operatorname{SE}(\hat{\beta_1})=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n-2}}\frac{s_Y}{s_{X_1}}\sqrt{1-r^2}$$

Where $s$ denotes the standard deviation and $r$ the correlation coefficient. In your example, the standard deviation of $Y$ is $100$ and that of $X_1$ is $1$. The correlation between $X_1$ and $Y$ is only $r=0.01$. So for $n=1000$, the standard error of $X_1$ is $3.165$. This means that in 95% of cases, the estimate $\hat{\beta_1}$ will be between $-5.20$ and $7.20$, which is a huge range compared to a coefficient of $1$. In the light of this, your result for `reg1` of $-0.3074$ is nothing out of the ordinary!

Let's confirm these calculations by looking at this simulation, where I repeat your process $10\,000$ times and store the regression coefficient each time:

```
set.seed(0)
n <- 1000

# Repeat the DGP 10000 times and store the coefficient estimate
res <- replicate(1e4, {
  X_1 <- rnorm(n)
  X_2 <- rnorm(n)
  Y <- X_1 + 100*X_2 + rnorm(n)  
  coef(lm(Y ~ X_1))[2]
})

# Plot and inspect the coefficient estimates
hist(res, breaks = "FD", col = "steelblue", las = 1, main = "", xlab = expression(widehat(beta[1])))
mean(res)
[1] 1.071695
sd(res)
[1] 3.148434
quantile(res, c(0.025, 0.975))
     2.5%     97.5% 
-5.159003  7.294270
```

[image: beta_hist]

We can see that the mean of all coefficients is nearly $1$, indicated in the histogram by the vertical orange line: The estimator seems to be unbiased. In this simulation, 95% of coefficient estimates were between $-5.16$ and $7.29$, confirming our theoretical calculations above.

Comment: Thanks, it's super clear !